# redirect after login laravel

Tags: redirect, laravel

I have these 2 routes. The first one redirects me to '/add' after successful login but there Auth::check always fails and answers 'not logged'. What am I doing wrong?

```
Route::post('/login', function() {
$log = Input::all();       
if (Auth::attempt(['user_name' => $log['username_log'], 'password' => $log['pass_log']])) {       
    return Redirect::intended('/add');
} else {
    return View::make('index', ['log_error' => '<p class="log_error">Incorrect username or password. Please, try again!</p>']);
}
```

});

```
Route::get('/add', function() {
if (Auth::check()) {
    echo 'logged';
} else {
    echo 'not logged';
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a filter, which will check if they're logged in. If they are they can proceed as you'd like them to, otherwise redirect them to the login form.

There's more information described here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

But by default there is an "auth" filter, so you'd use it like this:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'app'], function() {
    Route::intended('/app');
});
```

This will also help you get an understanding of it: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users